# Centering Objects on Stage, and Auto-Scaling with Stage Resize AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm writing a web based flash app that's written entirely in AS3.

I have objects on the screen as part of a GUI.  I would like the user to be able to resize the window, or make it full screen.  I would like everything to auto-scale with the resize, but also remain in the same relative position on the stage.

How can I go about achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/web-design/build-a-fluid-website-layout/).